# M-< and M-> not doing what it should on Windows

Tags: motion

I recently installed emacs 25 on my Windows 7 machine. Things are doing okay in general, but when I want to reach the top of buffer (M-<) or bottom of buffer (M->) it simply inserts the "<" or ">" in the text, as if I didn't press the meta key. Other meta combinations seem to be working fine. On Linux (Debian) it is working just fine.

I tried to google the problem but I haven't found any meaningful results. I don't really know what kind of information should I provide for this, so please ask if you need to know anything more. I am using a non-English keyboard layout, but I also use the same keyboard layout on Linux, and even if I switch to English layout it still doesn't work.

Comment: See this wiki article: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems#toc11

Comment: Are you using the terminal or the gui?

Comment: What @elethan said. Your Meta key is not working. Do `ESC <` and `ESC >` work for you? (That's the "Escape" key.)

Comment: @Dan I am using a GUI

Comment: @Drew Yes, escape makes it work. But how come other meta key combinations work with ALT, but this doesn't?

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte what command does it say `M->` and `M-<` are tied to if you do `C-h k` and then `M-<` or `M->`?

Comment: @elethan hmm it also doesn't register that I pressed the meta key, instead it displays the help for "<" only, which is the self-insert command. If I do C-h k ESC-< then it displays proper help text.

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte It is strange that the Alt key works for `M` in some cases. Maybe the default bindings are just different in your version of emacs. You could do something like `(global-set-key (kbd "M-<") 'beginning-of-buffer)` in your init file, to see if that works.

Comment: @elethan no that doesn't do anything :/ if the bindings were different, then I guess it wouldn't work with ESC either